# Small and inexpensive drive?

Tags: desktop, server, hard-disk

I am looking for a small drive of some sort for a private server hosted using a desktop computer.  The server will be used as a private proxy.  I only need around 25-50 GB, but everything I find is 500+ GB Hard Drives.  Is there a fast and small internal drive, maybe flash memory?  It would be best to spend less than $20.

[This](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822236811&ignorebbr=1) is the smallest drive I could find on Newegg, but it is still way too large and it 3 times the price I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find HDD's under $20 on newegg.com :

- 80 GB - WD800JD - [$9.99 on newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA5AD3S65663)
- WL 160GB - [$14.99 on newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA5AD3KE4385)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=32gb%20ssd&LH_PrefLoc=1)?

I bought a [2GB SSD](http://www.ebay.com/sch/sis.html?_nkw=DELL%20WYSE%20X90CW%202GB%20SATA%20SSD%20%28Apacer%20AP-SDM002G4LASS-KS%29%20%20%28PN%3A%208Y.F1B41.7504B%29&_id=141569410635&&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2658) for about $7 so I could build a pfSense router.  It was perfect for what I needed.  I also bought a 60GB HP SSD for $15.   There are plenty of drives (even new ones) for under $20.  It will just take some hunting.

Comment: I cannot buy the parts right now, and I was looking more off of eBay and on actual store sites for now, but here in a few months when I am back in the states I'll look on eBay if I cannot find anything else.